# platform independent .proj file

Tags: msbuild, mono, xbuild, path-separator

I want to use my .proj file for both msbuild and xbuild.
Currently I have paths like

```
$(ProjectDir)\..\..\
```

How can I re-write these paths so I can call xbuild on the proj file
without having to modify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xbuild is smart enough to handle the directory separators for you, so please stick to MSBuild style. You just need to pay attention to others.

Grab a Linux box and try it out.